# Kendo UI export to PDF multiple pages in .net

Tags: jquery, pdf, kendo-ui, telerik, export

I need to implement app for pdf export. When I search I fount kendo UI is best for my requirement. Also it's work very much until I export single page.

But when I export multiple page my kendo UI code doesn't work properly.

I my scenario I have main div as 'DivPrint' and two A4 size div inside it.**When I export it's export as 1 page instead of two pages.**

[image]

```
$scopeChild.generatePDF = function () {                                                


kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#DivPrint"), {paperSize: "A4",multiPage: true                                             })
            .then(function (group) {                                                    
              kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Converted PDF.pdf");
               })                                          
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `forcePageBreak` property available with Kendo and inside html, you should mention the classes.

Your HTML should be like this:

```
<div id="DivPrint">
 <div id="Div01">Text from first div </div>
 <div id="Div02" class="page-break">Text from second div</div>
<div>
```

And your JS should be like this:

```
kendo.drawing.drawDOM("#DivPrint", {
    paperSize: "A4",
    forcePageBreak: ".page-break"
  })
  .then(function(group) {
    kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Converted PDF.pdf");
  })
```

You can check the live demo here: https://jsbin.com/hedodigomu/

Answer (score 0):

```
function exportMultipleElements() {
    var exportSettings = {
        forcePageBreak: ".pageBreak",
        paperSize: "A3",
        landscape: true
    };
 
    var draw = kendo.drawing;
    var $ = $telerik.$;
    //use a few deferreds at once https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/
    //https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/drawing/methods/drawdom
    $.when(
        draw.drawDOM($("#first"), exportSettings),
        draw.drawDOM($("#second"), exportSettings),
        draw.drawDOM($("#third"), exportSettings),
        draw.drawDOM($("#fourth"), exportSettings)
    ).then(function (group1, group2, group3, group4) {//the number of arguments matches the number of deferreds
 
        var group = new kendo.drawing.Group({
            pdf: {
                multiPage: true
            }
        });
 
        //append the first three pages with the more static content, including the chart
        group.append(group1, group2, group3);
        //append the pages from the grid in the fourth element, see the rest of the functions in the full example to see how the page break selector is appended in the DOM
        group.append.apply(group, group4.children);
 
        return draw.exportPDF(group, exportSettings);
    }).done(function (data) {
        kendo.saveAs({
            dataURI: data,
            fileName: "multi-element-export.pdf"
        });
    });
}
```